# show that $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} v_{n}$exists.

Tags: real-analysis

For  $$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2/3&1/3\\ 1/3&2/3\end{array}\right).$$ and $$v=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a\\ b\end{array}\right)$$

we definie  a sequence  of vectors $v_{1}=v$,$ v_{n+1}=Av_{n}$. show that $
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} v_{n}$exists and is equal to $$v=\left(\begin{array}{cc}{(a+b)}/2\\ (a+b)/2\end{array}\right)$$

this is the orginal question

[image]

im completely struck  as  i don't know from where  i have to start ,,as i was taking  $v_{n+1} = Av_{n}$ ,taking  $v_{n+1} = v_n =  l$ now i got  $l= Al$ as  i got $A= I $ it gives me contradictionss,,,,

Pliz help  me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: $l= Al$ is not a contradiction, it means $l_1=2l_1/3+l_2/3, l_2=l_1/3+2l_2/3$, i.e. $l_1=l_2$. Moreover, $A$ is a (doubly) stochastic matrix, row and column sums are $1$. So multiplication by $A$ leaves the sum of both components invariant, it will always stay $a+b$. So if the limit exists, it has to be $\left(\begin{array}{cc}{(a+b)}/2\\ (a+b)/2\end{array}\right)$. That doesn't prove existence, but $A$ is contractive on $\{x:x_1+x_2=a+b\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1: Try to Diagonalize $A$. For instance, suppose that you were trying to solve the problem not with $A$, but with 
$$ B = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0  & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$ In what way would it be easier?

Approach 2: If you have learned about Markov matrices, apply the results for these kinds of matrices.

Note: Your approach of trying to solve $A v = v$, should not give you a contradiction. It should give you that $v$ is a multiple of the vector $ \begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},$ but that does not tell you that it equals $ \begin{bmatrix}  \frac{a+b}{2} \\ \frac{a+b}{2} \end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: im not getting .. can u elaborate in detail explanation????

Comment: That's not always possible, and the OP will hardly find your advice helpful.

Comment: $A$ is symmetric... you can diagonalize.

Try to diagonalize $A$, then update your post so people can further help you.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: Isn't $A$ positive definite? user357980: You should at least elaborate a little bit more and also write this as a hint.

Comment: @MrYouMath I know it *is* possible in this case, but the answer isn't intended for me, right? I doubt the OP has a clue what "diagonalize" means, or how it's done, and you don't really need to know for this problem.

Comment: This is a standard linear algebra problem done after diagonalization of matrices.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: Do you mean the op should determine $A^2$, ... and then guess the form of $A^n$, then verify by induction in order to determine $\lim_{n\to \infty}A^{n}$? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: @user357980: You should consider using bmatrix instead of pmatrix. It looks better

Comment: Thanks. I only knew about pmatrix.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure which looks better, but ok.

Answer (score 0):

$$ A=(1/3)BDB^{-1}$$ where $$B=  \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\ 1&-1\end{array}\right)$$ the matrix of eigenvectors,and

$$D=\left(\begin{array}{cc}3&0\\ 0&1\end{array}\right)$$

is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.

Thus $$ A^n=(1/3)^nBD^nB^{-1}$$

Note that we can find $A^nv$ using the above information.

Answer (score 0):

Alt. hint:   let $v_n=(a_n, b_n)^T$ then the recurrence can be written as:

$$
3a_{n+1}=2a_n+b_{n} \\
3b_{n+1}=a_n+2b_{n}
$$

Substituting $b_n=3a_{n+1}-2a_n$ from the first equation into the second one gives:

$$9a_{n+2}-6a_{n+1}=a_n+6a_{n+1}-4a_n \;\;\iff\;\; 3a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-a_n \quad \begin{cases}a_0 = a \\ a_1 = (2a+b)/3\end{cases}
$$

The latter is a regular linear homogeneous recurrence with constant coefficents which can be solved with the usual methods, or for a shortcut telescope $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}\left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right)$ twice.